# How do I sort in a Flex AdvancedDataGrid - callback isn't being called

Tags: apache-flex, sorting, advanceddatagrid

I have an AdvancedDataGrid that uses customer grouping of data. Not all of the groups will be at the same level in the hierarchy, and groups can contain both groups and members. We have a sort callback, but it's not being called except for groups at the leaf-most levels. See code below for an example -- expand all of the groups, then click the sort column on "date of birth" to get a reverse sort by date of birth. (Oddly, for some unfathomable reason, the first ascending sort works.)

We're not getting called for any of the data that's grouped at the same level as a group member.

How do I fix this?

Thanks.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:Application xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" 
     layout="vertical" 
     verticalAlign="middle" 
     backgroundColor="white" >
  <mx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
      import mx.controls.advancedDataGridClasses.AdvancedDataGridColumn;
      import mx.collections.HierarchicalData;
      import mx.utils.ObjectUtil;

      private var arrData : Array = [
        { name: "User A", dob: "04/14/1980" },
        { name: "User B", dob: "01/02/1975" },
        { name: "Group A", children: [
          { name: "User E", dob: "09/13/1972" },
          { name: "User F", dob: "11/22/1993" }
          ]
        },
        { name: "Group B", children: [
          { name: "Group B1", children: [
            { name: "User I", dob: "01/23/1984" },
            { name: "User J", dob: "11/10/1948" }
            ]
          },
          { name: "User G", dob: "04/09/1989" },
          { name: "User H", dob: "06/20/1963" }
          ]
        },
        { name: "User C", dob: "12/30/1977" },
        { name: "User D", dob: "10/27/1968" }
      ];

      private function date_sortCompareFunc(itemA:Object, itemB:Object):int
      {
        if ( itemA.hasOwnProperty("dob") && itemB.hasOwnProperty("dob"))
        {
          var dateA:Date = new Date(Date.parse(itemA.dob));
          var dateB:Date = new Date(Date.parse(itemB.dob));
          return ObjectUtil.dateCompare(dateA, dateB);
        }
        else if ( itemA.hasOwnProperty("dob"))
        {
          return 1;
        }
        else if (itemB.hasOwnProperty("dob"))
        {
          return -1;
        }
        return ObjectUtil.stringCompare(itemA.name, itemB.name);
      }

      private function date_dataTipFunc(item:Object):String
      {
        if (item.hasOwnProperty("dob"))
        {
          return dateFormatter.format(item.dob);
        }
        return "";
      }

      private function label_dob(item:Object, col:AdvancedDataGridColumn):String
      {
        var dob:String="";
        if(item.hasOwnProperty("dob"))
        {
          dob=item.dob;
        }
        return dob;
      }
    ]]>
  </mx:Script>

  <mx:DateFormatter id="dateFormatter" formatString="MMMM D, YYYY" />

  <mx:AdvancedDataGrid id="adgTest" dataProvider="{new HierarchicalData(this.arrData)}" designViewDataType="tree" width="746" height="400">
    <mx:columns>
      <mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn headerText="Name"  dataField="name"/>
      <mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn dataField="dob" headerText="Date of birth" 
           labelFunction="label_dob" 
           sortCompareFunction="date_sortCompareFunc"
           showDataTips="true" 
           dataTipFunction="date_dataTipFunc" />

    </mx:columns>
  </mx:AdvancedDataGrid>
</mx:Application>
```

Comment: Hi Shawn,

Did you figure out, why is sorting is not work in your case? I am trying to resolve similar issue with sortCompareFunction, my data is similar to yours: branches don't have same set of properties that leaf objects and sort callback only called first time.

Thx,
Irene

Answer (score 2):

It seems as if the first row contains null data or an empty string, and the advanceddatagrid is set to use grouped data, then the sort function doesn't get called.

it's a bit of a hack, yes, but if you can put in an unrealistic (say 1/1/1770), constant piece of data that you could insert at the database/file read/data input level then use the column labelFunction to render as null if the data matches that column, it should work, or at least the sort function will get called.

```
 public function dateCellLabel(item:Object, column:AdvancedDataGridColumn):String
    {
        var date:String = item[column.dataField];

        if (date=="1/1/1770") 
            return null; 
        else
            return  date;
    }
```

Sorry about answering this so late, but at least if somebody else tries to find the answer, they might see this.

Answer (score 0):

This has something to do with the logic of the SortCompareFunction.

Put `dob:"01/01/1970"` for all the group nodes and the sort works as expected, is that correct?

Comment: Yes, it works. But in the actual solution, it's not always feasible to add the field to each object.

If I put a breakpoint or tracing at the sort callback, the sort callback is never called for the other rows. By "logic of the SortCompareFunction", are you referring to the SortCompareFunction inside Flex, or the callback function above? I can't see anything odd in the SortCompareFunction above that would cause a problem, unless I'm not supposed to use "hasOwnProperty"?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the problem is to do with sorting grouped data with null or empty string values (which are perfectly valid values); the 
docs clearly state the property represented by `dataField` must be a valid property on the dataProvider [item] i.e. it must exist, null or otherwise.

While I give RaySir my vote, I don't quite agree that it's a hack, but rather you're normalizing your data, which I think is a perfectly fine presentation-layer thing to do.

Here's is a re-worked example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:Application xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" 
    layout="vertical" 
    verticalAlign="middle" 
    backgroundColor="white" >
    <mx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import mx.collections.HierarchicalData;
            import mx.controls.advancedDataGridClasses.AdvancedDataGridColumn;
            import mx.utils.ObjectUtil;

            private var arrData : Array = [
                { name: "User A", dob: "04/14/1980" },
                { name: "User B", dob: "01/02/1975" },
                { name: "Group A", dob: null, children: [
                    { name: "User E", dob: "09/13/1972" },
                    { name: "User F", dob: "11/22/1993" }
                ]
                },
                { name: "Group B", dob: null, children: [
                    { name: "Group B1", dob: null, children: [
                        { name: "User I", dob: "01/23/1984" },
                        { name: "User J", dob: "11/10/1948" }
                    ]
                    },
                    { name: "User G", dob: "04/09/1989" },
                    { name: "User H", dob: "06/20/1963" }
                ]
                },
                { name: "User C", dob: "12/30/1977" },
                { name: "User D", dob: "10/27/1968" }
            ];

            private function dob_sort(itemA:Object, itemB:Object):int {
                var dateA:Date = itemA.dob ? new Date(itemA.dob) : null;
                var dateB:Date = itemB.dob ? new Date(itemB.dob) : null;
                return ObjectUtil.dateCompare(dateA, dateB);
            }

            private function dob_dataTip(item:Object):String {
                if (!item.hasOwnProperty('children') && item.hasOwnProperty("dob")) {
                    return dateFormatter.format(item.dob);
                }
                return null;
            }

            private function dob_label(item:Object, col:AdvancedDataGridColumn):String {
                if(!item.hasOwnProperty('children') && item.hasOwnProperty("dob")) {
                    return item.dob;
                }
                return null;
            }
        ]]>
    </mx:Script>

    <mx:DateFormatter id="dateFormatter" formatString="MMMM D, YYYY" />

    <mx:AdvancedDataGrid id="adgTest" dataProvider="{new HierarchicalData(arrData)}" designViewDataType="tree" width="746" height="400">
        <mx:columns>
            <mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn headerText="Name"  dataField="name"/>
            <mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn headerText="Date of birth" dataField="dob"
                labelFunction="dob_label" 
                dataTipFunction="dob_dataTip"
                sortCompareFunction="dob_sort"
                showDataTips="true" />

        </mx:columns>
    </mx:AdvancedDataGrid>
</mx:Application>
```

Answer (score 0):

While it doesn't appear to be the case in this example, a missing dataField on a column will prevent sort from happening.  The systems are precisely as described, the sortCompareFunction is never called.

If you have a custom column renderer that is pulling fields out of data on its own, it's easy to overlook filling in a dataField attribute.  Everything will work fine, in that case, until you go to sort.  The sortCompareFunction will not be called.

Check by debuggging HierarchicalCollectionView.as, at line 1259 or so, in sortCanBeApplied.